# Enable Razor for Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I enable razor syntax (??) for my MVC project (New, not existing). I have visual studio 2010 Ultimate, and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2385361 update. Is there something else I need to install to enable the latest MVC (3??) options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to install ASP.NET MVC 3. Easiest way is through the Web Platform Installer (WebPI).

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

This will give you a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application template in File... New... Project... in VS2010. The wizard should default to Razor, though it's selectable in the View engine dropdown on the first (and only) page of the wizard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install MVC3 from Microsoft Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to install asp.net MVC version 3. Razor view engine is the default one then.